# adjusting li border-bottom "length"

Tags: html, css, border

This is css for an unordered-list with the id "leftmenu"

```
#leftmenu ul li{
list-style:none;
padding:15px 0 8px 0;
border-bottom:1px dashed white;
float:left;
clear:both;
```

The problem is the border only goes as far as the text go. see:https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyQ1V.jpg
I want it to be like that border under "Links"

Comment: Can u just remove `float: left`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your list-items should be displayed as regular block items. These would always scale to the full width of any container. For a `<li>` element that is actually the default behavior.

By setting `float: left;` to the `<li>` items, alter this behavior. The following code would achieve what you are after (also check the JS fiddle)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h4 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.menu {
    width: 200px;
}

.menu>ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu>ul>li {
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fhckxene/

edit: for fun play round with the jsfiddle, for example by adding `float: left;` or `display: inline-block;` to the `<li>` style.